# How to improve predictor importance in decision tree ensemble (using TreeBagger class in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

I'm trying to train a classifier (specifically, a decision forest) using the Matlab 'TreeBagger' class.

I notice from the online documentation for TreeBagger, that there are a couple of methods/properties that could be used to see how important each data point feature is for distinguishing between classes of data point.

The two I found were the ComputeOOBVarImp property and the ClassificationTree.predictorImportance method. Using the latter on a decision forest/bagged ensemble of trees that I'd built, I found that many data point features had zero importance for the classifier.

Is there anything I can do with the TreeBagger class, or in conjunction with it, so that my trees use weak learners/splitting criteria that aren't just bounds on single input data features, but linear combinations of these features, in order to improve the 'information gain' at each node split.

I suppose this comes down to dimensionality reduction of the data, that I have no experience in dealing with in Matlab.

Thanks.